# Accessing database depending on user role . using filters for secuirity here

Tags: grails, datasource

Using simple filters for login & security in my grails application.
now i need to connect to db - test1  using different login credential depending on logged in user role. if Admin logged in get write permission so different login & if user role logs in then read only.
How to implement it with filters??

DataSource.groovy

```
 environments {
 development {

/*IF LOGIN 'ADMIN' - SHOULD CONNECT USING THIS
 dataSource {
           username = 'admin'
           password = 'Guard1an'
           url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://test1:1433;
           MVCC=TRUE"
           dbCreate = 'update'
       }
/*IF LOGIN 'USER' - SHOULD CONNECT USING THIS*/

 dataSource {           
              dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
              username = 'user'
              password = 'tesoyear'
              url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://test1:1433;
        }
dataSource_wldb1 {
            username = 'gdx'
            password = 'pinoil'
            url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://wldb:1433/IVR_GUARDIAN"
            dbCreate = 'update'
    }
}
```

SecuirityFilter.groovy

```
   class SecurityFilters {
   def filters = {
   loginCheck(controller: 'load', action: '*') {
       before = {
          if (!session.user && !actionName.equals('login')) {
              flash.message = "User is not Logged in.Please login "
              redirect(controller:'user', action: 'index')
              return false
           }
       }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to secure controllers, it should be enough (and better) to use @Secured annotation. This allows you to secure whole controller or single method by specifing required user role(s). Check http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/ for more details. Below there is also an example.

If you are going to need more sophisticated security, check spring-security-acl plugin, which allow to grant permissions for specific database objects.

```
package org.example

import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured

class PostController {

    @Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
    def followAjax = { ... }

    @Secured(['ROLE_USER', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'])
    def addPostAjax = { ... }

    def global = { ... }

    @Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
    def timeline = { ... }

    @Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'])
    def personal = { ... }
}
```

Comment: well ,thanks for reply but i am not using spring security plugin so want to do it with simple filter(see my above code). is it possible without plugin?

Comment: I wrote this answer because there was a tag 'spring-security'. If you have already user in the session (you use it already in filter as `session.user`?), it's only a matter of querying some database/file for user roles. What exactly is your problem now?

Comment: Please see my datasource.groovy.this is loaded when i run-app the project before the user logs in & role in session so i want to do something so that datasource use separate credential for DB connectivity depending on which rle logged in. where to do it is my real question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question. You can check http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/ for your problem. Hope this helps.